# Removing [<] charecter from the particular tag in the xml using regex or shell

Tags: regex, xml, vim, sed

I'm new to regex that would be great if you can throw some light on this.

I have a big xml file which has around 50k lines constructed by some third party tool.

In which I have lines like this

```
<title>Apache 2.2 < 2.2.28 Multiple Vulnerabilities</title>
```

I just want remove the `<` inside this title tag in whole xml.

I tried some patterns in `vim` and `sed` but no luck.

Comment: Try `(<[^<]*>)|<` and replace with the first back-reference.

Comment: Hi stribizhev,Thanks for your response am running this regex in my vim :%s/(<[^<]*>)|<//gn
to replace the /  with empty but no luck correct me if am doing wrong

Comment: You need to replace with the first backreference, something like `:%s/\(<[^<]*>\)|</\1/g`. I guess you need to use `\(...\)` in vim to capture a substring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In vim you can do this:

```
:%s@\(<title>.*\)<\(.*</title>\)@\1\2@
```

(where `%` means 'the entire file', and `\1` and `\2` are back-references to the `\(..\)` parts of the expression)

Or, better yet:

```
:%s@\(<title>.\{-}\)<\(.\{-}</title>\)@\1\2@
```

(the `\{-}` is the non-greedy version of `*`).

However, I'm assuming that you want to replace the `<` because it is illegal XML syntax, you could replace it with `&amp;` like so:

```
:%s@\(<title>.\{-}\)<\(.\{-}</title>\)@\1\&amp;\2@
```

Comment: Hi Kenney,how to many this command global replace i tried with g at last but its replacing one at that line

Comment: Hi, sorry about that! Updated the answer. You'll want `:%s` to replace the entire file. `/g` means to replace all occurrences on a line, not just the first occurrence.

Comment: It Goes E488 Trailing charecters

Comment: Then there's probably something after your last `@`. Just copy one of the patterns from the answer into vim's commandline (and be sure there's no double `:` at the beginning of the line).

Comment: Regular expressions with vim or sed are somewhat unstandard; I usually use perl for this: `cat yourfile |  perl -ne 's@(<title>.*?)<(.*?</title>)@\1&amp;\2@; print' > newfile`.